# Rails: How to loading Animations with jQuery UJS in form submit button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I was working on trying to use jquery on my Login form button so that when a user clicks "Log In" the text changes into "Signing In.." for a better user experience. But I kept getting an error. I've placed my code below along with my error message. Any help would be amazing :) Thank you so much

**_login.html.erb (Working no jquery added)**

```
<div class="box" id="box2">
<p class="signinanywhere">Log into your account</p>
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
<%= f.label :email %><br />
<%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
<%= f.label :password %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
<div class="" id="rememberanywhere">
  <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
  <%= f.label :remember_me %>
</div>
  <% end -%>
  </div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <%- if devise_mapping.recoverable? && controller_name != 'passwords' && controller_name != 'registrations' %>
  <%= link_to "Forgot password?", new_password_path(resource_name), id: "forgotanywhere" %><br />
<% end -%>
</div>
</div>
  <div class="actions">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default custom" id="loginsubmit"> Log in</button>
  </div>
  <%- if devise_mapping.omniauthable? %>
  <%- resource_class.omniauth_providers.each do |provider| %>
<%= link_to "Sign in with #{OmniAuth::Utils.camelize(provider)}", omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider), id: "facebookanywhere", :class => "btn btn-primary" %><br />
  <% end -%>
<% end -%>
<% end %>
</div>
```

**_login.html.erb (Not working jquery added)**

```
<div class="actions">
<%= f.button type: :submit, "Log In".html_safe,  data: {disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Signing In..."} %>         
</div>
```

**Error Message**

```
SyntaxError at /
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
...e: :submit, "Log In".html_safe,  data: {disable_with: "<i cl...
...                               ^
/Users/oek203/Development/rails/sort2/app/views/pages/_login.html.erb:36: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting keyword_end
resource_class.omniauth_providers.each do |provider| 
^
/Users/oek203/Development/rails/sort2/app/views/pages/_login.html.erb:44: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation:

```
button(value = nil, options = {}, &block)
```

You need to pass the value first, then the options, try with:

```
<%= f.button 'Log In'.html_safe,
  type: :submit,
  data: { disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Signing In..." } %>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sebastian!! It worked beautifully, if I wanted to add a class and id so i can style my button would this be fine `<%= f.button 'Log In'.html_safe, class:"btn btn-default custom" id:"loginsubmit",  type: :submit,   :data => {:disable_with => "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Signing In..."} %>`

Comment: That's great! (note you missed a coma before the id).

Comment: Thanks a billion Sebastian :) have an amazing day champ

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
:data =>
```

instead of

```
data:
```

and

```
:disable_with =>
```

instead of

```
disable_with:
```

Hope this helps!

**Edit:**
Tested and working:

```
<%= f.button :submit, "Log In",  data: {disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Signing In...".html_safe} %>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help. It almost worked with your first two. But, I got an error message - sebastian spotted what was wrong - I had to pass the value "Log In" first. So this worked beautifully `<%= f.button 'Log In'.html_safe,  type: :submit,   :data => {:disable_with => "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Signing In..."} %>` Thank you so much again :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this:

```
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.button "Log In".html_safe,
      type: :submit,
      data: { disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Signing In..." } %>         
</div>
```

Comment: Why "Log In".html_safe?